# Checking for the amount of list item

Tags: android, listview

I need help on a if statement that checks to see if the listview has no items within the list and is empty. I assume I would need a boolean value but I have already tried list.getCount() == 0, but it hasn't worked along with some other methods. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: sorry, but you have to check documentation before asking

Comment: I did check the documentation that's how I got getCount() method, and that's the only method I could find resembling what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each android [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) should have [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). From the names you can see behaviours. And ListAdapter (for example [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)) provide relations between data (List) and UI (ListView).
So Adapter provide isEmpty() method.

```
boolean isEmpty = listView.getAdapter().isEmpty()
```

But be careful that you get adapter after set otherwise you will get NullPointerException on calling isEmpty() method.